# Get latest rows from my sql database

Tags: mysql

I have a table where there in rows there is a column called version. I have 2 same entries with 1 column say abc(unique) in all the same rows. I have 2 rows as follows

```
ID|Name|Version|Unique_Id
-------------------------
1 |abc |1      | 23
2 |abc1|2      |23
3 |xyz |1      |21
4 |tre |1      |20
```

I want the result as

```
ID|Name|Version|Unique_Id
-------------------------
2 |abc1|2      |23
3 |xyz |1      |21
4 |tre |1      |20
```

I have tried grouping by Unique_Id, the result is as follows

```
ID|Name|Version|Unique_Id
-------------------------
1 |abc |1      | 23
3 |xyz |1      |21
4 |tre |1      |20
```

Following is the query I am using

```
SELECT *  FROM test
group by Unique_Id
order by Version desc;
```

I want latest(top order by desc) of each each rows. Please help. How can i achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
INSERT INTO tbllogs 
            (logorigin, 
             logaction, 
             loguser, 
             logdate, 
             logoutcome) 
VALUES      (:origin, 
             :action, 
             :user, 
             :dt, 
             :outcome)
```

Use a sub select to determine the id and its max version number, then join back to the original table to retrieve the other values.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a737/1)

Comment: Thanks man.... it worked. Can you please explain me the query. It will be much helpful. I want to do it in LINQ also. Can you help me with that also.? I am fairly new to all these technologies.

Comment: OK, the initial sub select retieves the MAX version number per unique ID, once you have this you JOIN back to the original table to retrieve the rows in question.

Comment: @user2998990 Try running his inner query by itself and see what you get.  He joins this inner result to the original table to get the result you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  : I tried.. as i want all the rows(top) the inner query gives me right result but when I seect * it gives me wrong result.

Comment: @AdriaanStander : Awesome.. Can you please help me in converting the query to LINQ statement. Please.